# Cumulatively add numbers with python's map function

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Hi friends I want to perform an operation I believe I can solve this with map.

The following operation is actually working correctly. But I want to do something a bit different.

18 will be 19 when it increases. But when the next value comes, it will now be collected with 19.

in this example, the output I want is:

```
>> [18,18,18,19,19,21]
```

This is what I can do:

```
def sum(x):
    return x+18

new_list = list(map(sum, [0,0,0,1,0,2]))

>> [18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 20]
```

Comment: First, naming your function `sum`, and hiding the builtin of that name, is confusing.

Comment: But meanwhile, I think what you want here is [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), not `map`. You do want to add a starting value, but there are two easy ways to do that: (1) chain the starting value onto the input before calling `accumulate` then skip over it in the output, or (2) copy the "roughly equivalent to" code in the docs and write your own version that takes a start value as an additional parameter.

Comment: @abarnert: Though `itertools.accumulate` isn't an option here, since the OP is using 2.7 (`accumulate` was added in 3.2). So you'd need to use `map` and a stateful mapping function (e.g. a class implementing `__call__` that would maintain the running sum).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Or you can just copy the `accumulate` "roughly equivalent" code from the 3.2 docs, which work in 2.7. (I was fooled by him explicitly calling `list(map(…))`, which is pointless in 2.7…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function which *is* present in 2.7?  `reduce` is often used in conjunction with `map` to aggregate lists after some number of map transformations.

Here's my 3.5 version of it, which should be close, if not identical to 2.7:

```
startVal =  18
myList   =  [0,0,0,1,0,2]
accumulator = reduce((lambda x, y: ( x + [y + (0 if len(x) == 0 else x[-1])])), myList, [])  
[startVal + v for v in accumulator]

>> [18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21]
```

I'm taking advantage of addition of lists (which concatenates) to append subsequent values to the empty list defined in the initializer.  There's a little conditional since you can't get the last entry of an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do what you want with `map` will require adding some kind of "memory" to the function—it has to know what it's done so far, so it knows what to do next.

You *can* do this, either by using a closure, or by using a class with a `__call__` method. But there's an easier way.

What you're looking for is almost exactly the [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function. The only difference is that you want to supply a starting value. (And, of course, that `accumulate` isn't actually in the stdlib in 2.7; you need to get it off a backport on PyPI.)

You could handle that in three obvious ways:

- `accumulate`, then add your starting value to each element.
- `chain` a starting value before the input, then `accumulate`, then `next` (or `islice`) to skip over the extra value in the output.
- Take the "roughly equivalent" sample code in the `accumulate` docs and modify it to take a start value.

Let's do the last one—it's probably the heaviest-weight option, but the one you can learn the most from, plus it'll work even in 2.7 without any backports:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add, start=0):
    'Return running totals'
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = start
    try:
        total += next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return total
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

Compare to the original code in the docs—all I did was add a new parameter, set `total = start`, and change the special handling for the first element or for empty iterables. You can obviously simplify things (if we have a start value, we don't even *need* special handling for empty input), or make things fancier (default to no start value instead of 0, so `accumulate` works for types that aren't interoperable with int just like the one in `itertools` does), etc., but this is a simple starting point.

And now:

```
>>> new_list = accumulate([0,0,0,1,0,2], start=18)
>>> new_list
[18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 20]
```